# How Do I Edit the Location of a Photo in iPhoto ’09?

Tags: mac, iphoto

I’ve taken a photo with my iPhone’s camera and imported it into iPhoto ’09, but it shows up in the wrong place on the map. Can I edit the photo’s location in iPhoto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the "i" on the bottom right of the photo or the event.
2. Click the current wrong location, then type the correct address and press search.
3. See if the search result is what you want.
4. Click "Assign to event" when done.
5. "Done".

Answer (score 1):

In the multiple photo view, click the *i* on the bottom right of the photo, then select "new place". You should be able to change it there.